# How to handle a new window in selenium when I opened it by javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium in internet explorer I have opened a new window with javascript code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("windows.open('www.google.com')");
```

When I try to move to that new window selenium does not detect the window. At the time of printing the number of windows opened by the driver I only get 1:

```
Set<String> handlesSet = visor.getWindowHandles();
List<String> handlesList = new ArrayList<String>(handlesSet);
System.out.println("open windows: " + handlesList.size());
```

**My question**: ¿Is it possible to manage that new window opened from javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: Three clarifying questions: First, does the new window handle show up after a delay? Second, are your Protected Mode settings properly set? Third, what does a `TRACE` level log of IEDriverServer.exe show you?

Comment: I have put a delay of 10 seconds and the window handle does not appear. 
I have set: _ignoreProtectedModeSettings_ in true. 
¿where can I see the trace of the IEDriverServer?

Comment: If you have `ignoreProtectedModeSettings` set to true, that is quite likely the issue. Configure the browser properly for use with the driver by setting Protected Mode to the same value (on _or_ off, either will work) for all zones.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `windows`, it should `window`, without `s`:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('https://www.google.com')");
```

Don't forget to put full url with `https://`